# SQL: Not overwrite tablecell if value is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm wondering if it is possible to update a SQL row only with **not** empty values.

A user wants to update its accountdata and leaves the email field in a html-form blank. The resulting PHP-array should gets updated to the database, but only the values, which are **not** blank:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 9505399
    [first_name] => Max
    [last_name] => Mustermann
    [email] => 
    [location] => cologne
    [country] => germany
)
```

SQL-Update:

```
$sql = "UPDATE  observation
    SET id       = :id,
      first_name = :first_name,
      last_name  = :last_name,
      email      = :email,
      location   = :location,
      country    = :country
    WHERE id = :id";
```

**Problem**: If the user has set his email before, this SQL-update will overwrite the existing entry (email) with an empty value. I need to prevent that the cell gets overwrite by an empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_filter()` to remove empty values from your array. Then you could build your query dynamically like this :

```
$arr = array_filter($arr); // remove empty values
$args = [];
$qryargs = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $args[':'.$key] = $val ; // populate query arguments 
    if ($key == 'id') continue ; // remove id from SET statement
    $qryargs[] = $key . ' = :' . $key;
}
// build query string
$sql = "UPDATE  observation SET " . implode(', ', $qryargs). " WHERE id = :id";

echo $sql ;
print_r($args);
```

Outputs :

```
UPDATE  observation SET first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name, 
        location = :location, country = :country WHERE id = :id

Array
(
    [:id] => 9505399
    [:first_name] => Max
    [:last_name] => Mustermann
    [:location] => cologne
    [:country] => germany
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure SQL solution, you can use CASE statement:

```
UPDATE observation
SET 
first_name = CASE
   WHEN first_name IS NULL OR first_name = '' THEN :first_name
   WHEN first_name <> 0 THEN first_name 
END,
last_name = ...
WHERE id = :id;
```

Also, I believe, that you don't really want to update user's id each time.